# Wordpress strange behavior of 3 dots in title of wordpress post

Tags: html, css, wordpress

In wordpress I've put 'Postcards from...' in the title of the post.

When I want to display the title in my custom theme in wordpress, the three dots at the end of the title change the font for this title.

this is what I have in my custom theme html

```
<p><span><?php the_title(); ?></span></p>
```

This is what the page source shows me

```
<p><span>Postcards From&#8230;</span></p>
```

How does that happen, or what does that mean and how to work around that. 2 dots behind the title works fine it doesn't change the font. 3 dots or more gives this weird code or changes the way it displays the font of the title.

Thanks for your help

Comment: do you have a link to the site?

Comment: This may not work, but I would try changing your title within your WP editor to "Postcards From&#8230;". `&#8230;` is the HTML code for an ellipses. Let me know if that does anything, or a link to your site would also be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is performed by the function wptexturize, which automatically converts ... into an ellipsis character.

This is applied to the content, excerpt, title and more as defined in wp-includes/default-filters.php.

You can remove the wptexturize filter completely but it does much more than just create the ellipsis characters so your best bet for just removing the ellipsis would be to convert them back.
i.e.

```
function title_remove_ellipsis( $title ){
    return str_replace( '&#8230;', '...', $title );
}
add_filter( 'the_title', 'title_remove_ellipsis', 20 );
```

You can add this either through a plugin or your themes functions.php file.

Comment: Thanks for helping me out. I've put your code in my funtion.php and it solved the problem.